# :: jQuery :: Delete dynamically created new items from different elements with same index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding custom font names to the selectbox dropdown and **New fonts** list.

Along with adding, need to provide delete font as well.

Eg: If I delete font **A** from the list (this is working), same font should be deleted from the dropdown list as well (Not working)

**http://jsfiddle.net/32wpa9rx/**

**Code below**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addFont', function(){
  var _font_name = jQuery('#fontName').val();
  var _font_name_short = _font_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  jQuery('select#fonts option').removeAttr('selected');
  jQuery('select#fonts').prepend('<option value="'+_font_name+'" custom-font="'+_font_name_short+'" selected>'+_font_name+'</option>');
  jQuery('ul#newFonts').prepend('<li custom-font="'+_font_name_short+'">'+_font_name+' <a href="javascript:;" class="remove-font">Remove</a></li>');
  jQuery('#fontName').val('');
})

$(document).on('click', '.remove-font', function(){
  var selectedFont = jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('custom-font');
  var ddFont = $("select#fonts option").attr('custom-font')
  jQuery(this).closest('li').remove();
  if (selectedFont == ddFont){
    jQuery(ddFont).remove();
  }
})
```

```css
div{margin-top:15px;}
a{margin-left:5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="fonts">
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<input id="fontName" type="text" placeholder="Font name">
<button type="submit" id="addFont">Add font</button>

<div>
  <b>New fonts</b>
  <ul id="newFonts"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$("select#fonts option[value='"+selectedFont+"']").remove();` to remove the font from the select

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#addFont', function() {
  var _font_name = jQuery('#fontName').val();
  var _font_name_short = _font_name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
  jQuery('select#fonts option').removeAttr('selected');
  jQuery('select#fonts').prepend('<option value="' + _font_name + '" custom-font="' + _font_name_short + '" selected>' + _font_name + '</option>');
  jQuery('ul#newFonts').prepend('<li custom-font="' + _font_name_short + '">' + _font_name + ' <a href="javascript:;" class="remove-font">Remove</a></li>');
  jQuery('#fontName').val('');
})

$(document).on('click', '.remove-font', function() {
  var selectedFont = jQuery(this).closest('li').attr('custom-font');
  $("select#fonts option[value='"+selectedFont+"']").remove();
  jQuery(this).closest('li').remove();
})
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

a {
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="fonts">
  <option value="arial">Arial</option>
  <option value="verdana">Verdana</option>
</select>

<input id="fontName" type="text" placeholder="Font name">
<button type="submit" id="addFont">Add font</button>

<div>
  <b>New fonts</b>
  <ul id="newFonts"></ul>
</div>
```